# No Kubernetes Option in Docker Desktop for Windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows, configuration

Just getting started on Docker and after installing Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 Pro machine, the option to enable Kubernetes is missing from the context menu when using Windows containers. See the attached image. When I switch to Linux containers the option appears. Various reading I've done seems to indicate that it should be available to Windows containers too. What am I missing?

Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134.1006)

Docker Desktop 2.1.0.5

[image]

After update:

[image]

Settings after update:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first switch to Edge version by going to the

Docker -> Settings -> General tab.

Then, you have to enable the kubernetes.

> Open Docker for Windows settings by accessing your system tray and navigate to the Kubernetes tab. Select the checkbox for Enable Kubernetes to start a single-node cluster when starting Docker.

Reference: https://medium.com/@damiannolan/kubernetes-on-docker-for-windows-5ca0c6395668

As per this old [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56157504/how-to-run-windows-containers-on-local-kubernetes) and a [latest one](https://blog.sixeyed.com/getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-windows/), Kubernetes needs a Linux master node and thus the kubernetes cluster can be initialized only from `linux containers` in Docker desktop for Windows. After enabling and starting the docker containers, you can add Windows containers the the running kubernetes cluster.

[This](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2019/03/25/windows-server-containers-now-supported-kubernetes/) will give you much clear context.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted if it solved the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however after I updated to 2.1.7.0 edge, the option still doesn't appear with Windows containers.

Comment: What all options you see when you click on `settings`

Comment: Left side tabs: General, Resources, Docker Engine, Command Line

Comment: Updated original post with screen caps

Comment: unfortunately, kubernetes cannot be enabled from `Windows containers` option as the kubernetes control plane must be running on Linux container. I've updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

As Samit commented, the options for Kubernetes are only available if Linux containers are currently set as the environment.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had installed some version or configuration of docker that I got from a Udemy course. There was no Kubernetes anywhere. Once I removed that version of docker and installed a new one downloaded from https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/ , the k8s option was there.

Comment: The similar issue has happend to me. I didn't see K8s menu item in General settings. Once I've ununstall and downloaded from official site I was starting to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issues with Docker Windows. I realized we need to switch to linux by clicking on **windows tray right click docker** as below:

[image: Switch to Linux Conatiners]ur.com/C0e4r.png

Please note, if your previous images are on windows you need to run the same process after switching to linux and then continue with your Kubernetes kubectl